# nopcommerce and appharbor no admin page found

Tags: nopcommerce, appharbor

I already have nopCommerce in AppHarbor. When I click the administration link. it says Page Not Found. How do you install nopCommerce in AppHarbor properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you deploy yourself?  Which version of nopCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your \bin directory and ensure that Nop.Admin.dll is there. If it doesn't exist, then looks like you haven't re-build the solution before publishing

Answer (score 0):

I just copied **Nop.Admin.dll**  on folder **Nop.web\bin** and it worked fine for me, earlier this DLL **Nop.Admin.dll** was missing from stuff.